# How to pass value to qweb view from ir_config_parameter

Tags: xml, odoo

i want to pass value from ir_config_parameter to qweb view 't-name="web.ControlPanel"'.

I tried something like this but it doesn't work

`<t t-set="wanted_parameter" t-value="env['ir.config_parameter'].get_param('wanted_parameter')">`

Answer (score 0):

Could be accomplished by adding a compute field to your model and using it in your QWeb view.

```
wanted_parameter = fields.Boolean(string='Setting', compute='_compute_wanted_parameter')

def _compute_wanted_parameter(self):
    for rec in self:
        config = self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo()
        get_wanted_parameter = config.get_param('wanted_parameter', False)
        rec.wanted_parameter = get_wanted_parameter
```

In your QWeb, use the computed field:

```
<t t-set="wanted_parameter" t-value="record.wanted_parameter"/>
```

Comment: but in this qweb template i have no option to attach to record. This is a base owl template in web addon (base.xml file).

Answer (score 0):

You can override `session_info`

***Example:***

```py
from odoo import api, http, models


class Http(models.AbstractModel):
    _inherit = 'ir.http'

    def session_info(self):
        session_info =  super().session_info()
        if self.env.user.has_group('base.group_user'):
            IrConfigSudo = self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo()
            session_info.update({
                "wanted_parameter": IrConfigSudo.get_param(wanted_parameter)
            })
        return session_info
```

You can access the session info through `env.session`

***Example:***

```
<t t-esc="env.session.wanted_parameter"/>
```